# Need layout design suggestion

Tags: android

[image]

I need to create layout as like the above design in android, i'm confused to go with listview or grid view, i'm comfortable with listview but how i can make column size dynamic, because column size varies based on the web service result for a particular row. please provide me some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not use any scrollviews.

Why?

because it keeps all of your images in memory and if you have multiple items you will get OOM exception very quickly.

Solution:

Create a `RecyclerView` as a root view with a `LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL` as a `LayoutManager`. for each row you can put another `RecyclerView` but now with a `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` as a `LayoutManager`.

Take a look at [How to create scrollable page of carousels in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077878/how-to-create-scrollable-page-of-carousels-in-android/27311842#27311842)

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, with reference.

Comment: you are always welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make whole scroll layout and inside scroll layout make horizontal scroll layout .
See below :-

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>
            <HorizontalScrollView>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>
            <HorizontalScrollView>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>
            <HorizontalScrollView>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout>
            <HorizontalScrollView>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```