# RecyclerView row items allowing horizontal scroll

Tags: android, android-layout

**Can I make the RecyclerView row items to allow horizontally scrolling?** Each item (card layout for example or any other) is a category item and each category has multiple items that can be scrolled on horizontal...

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077878/how-to-create-scrollable-page-of-carousels-in-android/27311842#27311842

Comment: + MHossein - please leave a reply to accept you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create scrollable page of carousels in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077878/how-to-create-scrollable-page-of-carousels-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested you try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077878/how-to-create-scrollable-page-of-carousels-in-android/27311842#27311842). for myself is usefull. you must using in every row a Horizontal Recyclerview.

Comment: If another question has an answer that fits perfectly to this one, you are supposed to flag it as a duplicate of that one or to vote to close it, not to answer it with a link only.

Answer (score -1):

set Orientation to RecyclerView

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(), myData, myLayout);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        // for horizontal
           linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        // for vertical 
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Comment: i think he means that the recycler view should scroll vertically, but each item can be independently scrolled horizontally

Comment: In that case we have to take two RecylerViews one is parent Vertical orientation and second is child Horizontal orientation